# Unity 3.5: Retrieve concrete implementation by its open generic interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

This blog post describes a nice alternative to the Repository pattern.

https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

Instead of Repositories the author recommends the use of Commands and Queries. The particular blog post describes the implementation of the Query part in .NET/C#.

There are two interfaces for the query and for the query handler:

```
public interface IQuery<TResult>
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

He also offers an example for each:

```
public class FindUsersBySearchTextQuery : IQuery<User[]>
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }

    public bool IncludeInactiveUsers { get; set; }
}

public class FindUsersBySearchTextQueryHandler
    : IQueryHandler<FindUsersBySearchTextQuery, User[]>
{
    private readonly NorthwindUnitOfWork db;

    public FindUsersBySearchTextQueryHandler(NorthwindUnitOfWork db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public User[] Handle(FindUsersBySearchTextQuery query)
    {
        return (
            from user in this.db.Users
            where user.Name.Contains(query.SearchText)
            select user)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

The query handler can be provided as a constructor parameter to a MVC controller.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    IQueryHandler<FindUsersBySearchTextQuery, User[]> handler;

    public UserController(IQueryHandler<FindUsersBySearchTextQuery, User[]> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public View SearchUsers(string searchString)
    {
        var query = new FindUsersBySearchTextQuery
        {
            SearchText = searchString,
            IncludeInactiveUsers = false
        };

        User[] users = this.handler.Handle(query);

        return this.View(users);
    }
}
```

The author uses the dependency injection container Simple Injector to register all IQueryHandler's at once:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IQueryHandler<,>),
    typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).Assembly);
```

**My question is: How can I do this last statement in Unity?**

I'm using Unity 3.5.

I'm able to register each QueryHandler manually, like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IQueryHandler<FindUsersBySearchTextQuery, User[]>, 
                       FindUsersBySearchTextQueryHandler>();
```

This works fine but I don't want to add a new mapping each time a new QueryHandler comes up. I want to set up all mappings with one convention which includes future QueryHandler's. Unity 3.5 offers a convention based registration workflow but I could not make it work for my case. I tried this but unfortunately it does not generate the mappings in question.

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to have many specific implementations of `IQueryHandler<,>` and not one generic version, then you can't use open generics to register.  But you can use reflection to find all implementations and register them each.  (This is what RegisterTypes does behind the scenes for you).

You were close with your attempt at the RegisterTypes call in the question, but you used `WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface`.  This will only register classes with their interface that matches by the naming convention of `MyClass : IMyClass` (prepending an `'I'` to the class name).  If you instead register with `WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces` you will get the registrations you are after.

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.Default);
```

---

If you need to only register those classes, you can filter down the classes to only those that implement the interface you are after...

```
public static class EnumerableTypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> WhichImplementsInterface<T>
        (this IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        return types.WhichImplementsInterface(typeof (T));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> WhichImplementsInterface
        (this IEnumerable<Type> types, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return types.WhichImplementsInterface(interfaceType.Name);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> WhichImplementsInterface
        (this IEnumerable<Type> types, string interfaceTypeName)
    {
        return types.Where(t => t.GetInterface(interfaceTypeName) != null);
    }
}
```

Then you can use these filters like this...

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().WhichImplementsInterface(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.Default);
```